# Featured page in wordpress sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a 'featured page' button/widget to a sidebar in Wordpress that will show a thumbnail of the page as well as the page's custom excerpt (I'm using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-excerpt/).

I got it sort of working using either a custom text widget or http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-page-widget/ but it doesn't show the excerpt, it just generates one from the page's main content.

Anyone know an easy way to do this? My hope was for non-web designers to be able to update this kind of content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by activating this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-text-widget/ You can put your php code in the widget. This means you can also put your WP_QUERY, query_posts or get_posts loop in order for you to get the page you want.

Activate the plugin go to your widget page use the **text widget** and drag it to your widget area and paste this

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query();
$the_query->query("page_id=$page_id");
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
  //show thumbnail
   if(has_post_thumbnail()) :
     the_post_thumbnail(); 
 endif; 
 //show excerpt
   the_excerpt();
endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for referring me to that widget. I'm trying to show a specific page title, thumbnail, and excerpt, but so far I can only get the title to appear. I've asked this as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237142/show-wordpress-page-excerpt

Comment: Did you use the code above? Just replace the $page_id with your ID

Comment: I tried that, but it pulled the page title and content, no thumbnail and no excerpt.

Comment: I think I found some useful snippets here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60304/get-page-title-url-and-excerpt-of-a-page

Comment: Update! update! this plugin is much better http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-text-widget/